# SortBy the second element in the sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Is there a way to sort sublists in a list by the sublists' second element?

For example, if the list is:

```
alist = {{1, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 6, 1}, {0, 9, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 7, 9}}

SortBy[alist, #2 &]
```

I wanted to use this to sort by **5,3,9,3,7**, but failed. So what is the right code?

If sort by the first values, then the second, then the third, till the end of the sub-lists, what should I do?

Comment: `SortBy[alist, #[[2]] &]`

Comment: Yes. If I need to do all the sorting, should I do `SortBy[SortBy[
  SortBy[{{1, 5, 2}, {1, 3, 6, 1}, {0, 9, 1}, {0, 3, 2}, {0, 7,9}}, #[[1]] &], #[[2]] &], #[[3]] &]`. Do you feel this is too bloated？@Syed

Comment: `SortBy` will take multiple functions to successively sort lists. Please look at the docs. It is the second syntax. For example: `SortBy[alist, {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &]`

Comment: @Syed Thanks. I see it.

Comment: Are you sure that string of `SortBy` does what you want? Are you just looking for `SortBy[lst, #[[1 ;; 3]] &]` or equivalently `SortBy[lst,Take[3]]`?

Comment: @Alan I am confused by these. May you tell me what is the exact difference among them? I tested and I found `SortBy[alist, {#[[1]], #[[2]],#[[3]]} &]` equivalent to `SortBy[lst, #[[1 ;; 3]] &]`. What is the `SortBy[lst,Take[3]]`?

Comment: It is a brain fart. I sometimes forget that take does not have an operator form (for some reason). So `SortBy[lst,Take[#,3]&]`. But my point was that Mma already does lexicographic sort of lists.